# Scenes are messed up and overlapping

Tags: godot

A very strange phenomnenon is happening to me right now. All of my scenes are seeming to overlap each other in the main scene. I believe that the cause might be when I change scenes, but it has never happened before.

```
func _process(delta):
    if one_is_pressed and encounter:
        $HUD/EventUnfolder.hide()
        get_tree().paused = false
        enemy_attack = true

        encounter = false
        one_is_pressed = false
    
    if one_is_pressed and market:
        $HUD/EventUnfolder.hide()
        
        one_is_pressed = false
        
        get_tree().change_scene("res://Market.tscn")
```

This is one of the bits of script where I change the scene, and it is coming from the main scene. Instead of changing to the market scene, which is a 2D scene with some buttons, the market buttons appear in the Main scene. Help?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what's going on in your code but maybe try `elif` instead of the second `if`? something like [this](https://pastecode.io/s/ukpkb8ek)?

Comment: No, it's still happening. What's even more strange is that when running the Market scene straight from the editor (clicking on play this scene) the Main scene is instanced into it and is still playing. Instead of a 2D button space with 2 buttons, those two buttons are again in the Main scene. As I said, this happens even when directly starting the specific scene from the editor.

Comment: Do you have anything in your [Singletons (AutoLoad)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html)? because best I know that's the only thing that "follows" you no matter what scene you load

Comment: Ok, so I removed the Main singleton, which is the singleton connecting to the Main scene, and it worked, meaning the Market scene is it's own thing now, as well as future scenes. I still don't entirely know why the singleton caused this, but I will try to be more careful with my singletons in the future.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but I don't think you're suppose to set your Main scene as a singleton rather [set it as the main scene in the project settings](https://godotengine.org/qa/98993/how-choose-which-scene-first-displayed-when-the-game-loaded)